# Can I start the same thread two times at the same block?

Tags: java

I start the same thread two times on two lines,

```
new MyThread(0).start();
new MyThread(1).start();
```

can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are different **instances** of the same **type**, and definitely not the same thread, you can do this.

This notation could make it clearer why (though it is equivalent with the original apart from the output line):

```
Thread instance1 = new MyThread(0); //created one instance
Thread instance2 = new MyThread(1); //created another instance

//we have two different instances now
// let's see if that is true, or not:
System.out.println("The two threads are " + (instance1==instance2?"the same":"different"));

instance1.start(); //start first thread instance
instance2.start(); //start second instance 

//we just started the two different threads
```

However, depending the implementation of `MyThread`, this **might** pose problems. Multithreaded programming is ain't no easy. The thread instances should be operating in a thread-safe way, and that is not trivial to guarrantee.

Recommended reading: [Java Concurrency In Practice (Peierls, Bloch, Bowbeer, Holmes, Lea)](http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/)

Comment: @ppeterka Most of the time it's *low hanging fruit*. Lots of reps with little effort.

Comment: Does instance1 running precede instance2 running?

Comment: @ppeterka How to let the instance1 precede instance2 to run?

Comment: @VictorS that would defy the cause of using Threads! Why do you want to do that? (By the way, to answer your question: using `instance1.run(); instance2.run();` This will execute the contents of the `run()` method on the same thread as the main one.)

Comment: @ppeterka Thanks for your answer, I completely confused that whether I should use two threads, they are invoke the same method and do the same function only using different argument.

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29) says, you cannot start a thread more than once - if you call `start()` on a thread that has already been started, you'll get an `IllegalThreadStateException`.

However, your code does not do what you say: you are **not** starting the same thread twice with that code - you're creating two separate `MyThread` objects which you start.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you are instantiating two threads.

Though they have the same class (`MyThread`), every time you use the `new` keyword in java, you instantiate a new object.  This new object can not share data with the original object.  You have created two separate `MyThread` objects; you could start one and not the other, or start both.